# APK Signing Issue

Tags: android

I have an issue which is related to an app that I have in Google Play, and I am planning to update it.

The issue that although I still have the previous key but I am not sure why Google Play Control is complaining that I don't have the same fingerprint

See below picture

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: sign with Android Studio -> Build -> Generate Signed APK. Ensure that if you sign v2, the v1 checkbox should be checked also.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Generate Signed APK" with the same key store, key alias with v1 and v2 checkbox. If you lost one of them, Google store will not accept it.

If you want to update unpublish app, you can remove it and create a new project.
If the app is published, it can't be removed from the store.